# Sorting content of a .txt file in Python 3 line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort content of a .txt file that is read into Python from its highest to lowest numeric value.

[image]

Using the following code:

```
with open("externalFile.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
    print(content)

list = content.splitlines()

def f(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def f1(text):
    return [ func(z) for z in re.split('(\d+)', text) ]

list.sort(key=f1)
```

creates a list and within that list it sorts the content both alphabetically and numerically, as shown below.

[image]

However, I only want the content to be sorted numerically in Python, please see below.

[image]

Comment: Why the images?

Comment: instead of adding images, can you add actual content of your files in the post?

Comment: What is ``func``? Is it ``f``? Why do you sort by both fields if you only care about the later?

Comment: Leave out the label in the key function. Return only the number.

Comment: @ForceBru: well intentioned as it may be, inlining images of what should be plain text is not very helpful. In fact, it is the contrary -- it suggests the OP *this* is the correct way.

Comment: @usr2564301, it's still better than having to click on links to view the images, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, func is f.

Comment: Why does `f1` return a list? Shouldn't it just return a number?

Comment: I'm confused. Your file does not contain a 58, so why does your desired output have a 58?

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that I am new to asking questions on this platform.  I have merely added those pictures for clarification as to how I want the data to be sorted in Python.

Comment: But including them as text allows us to copy it, instead of typing it over -- and possibly making errors in that. It is also, from your side, *much* easier to do. (If you properly include the text, at least one downvote will go away.)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
def f1(text):
    name, _, num = text.partition(':')
    return int(num)


with open("sorting.txt", "r") as file:
    l = file.read().splitlines()
    l.sort(key=f1, reverse=True)
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to sort numerically, you can use list comprehension,

```
with open("d:/data.txt") as file:
    read_as_lit = [line.strip().split(":") for line in file]
    sorted_file = sorted(read_as_lit, key=lambda y:int(y[1]), reverse=True)


print(sorted_file)

[['alpha', ' 50'], ['gamma', ' 45'], ['beta', ' 30'], ['alpha', ' 20'], ['gamma', ' 10'], ['alpha', ' 10']]
```